# Unable to access bitbucket from remote server using SSH key to perform a git pull on latest code in repository

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04, ssh-keys

I'm trying to pull the latest code on bitbucket into a development (Ubuntu) server using the git pull command.  The git pull command attempts to access bitbucket as root user via a SSH connection, but also asks for a paraphrase pertaining to the SSH.  The root/.ssh folder on the Ubuntu server contain id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files, but I'm unable to add the pubic key from id_rsa.pub to bitbucket because apparently that key is being used by someone else.  I also don't know the paraphrase pertaining to this SSH key.  So couple of questions:

1. How is the remote server connecting to the bitbucket repository via SSH when I'm unable to add the SSH public key to bitbucket?
2. Should I instead create a new SSH key in the Ubuntu server and try to add that (the public key part) to bitbucket, then access bitbucket using the new key?
3. If I don't have the paraphrase that the server keeps prompting me to enter after typing the git pull command, what's the best approach to pulling code from the repository?  Here are a few I can think of, but appreciate guidance on the best approach:

A) Create new SSH key (with or without a paraphrase, though i think having a paraphrase is safer), add the new public key to bitbucket, then attempt to pull code off bitbucket via SSH.  I would think that the server will still try to access bitbucket as root user, not as the username I use to log into the server.  This of course will require me to first get read-write-execute privileges to the /root and /root/.ssh folders (on my server, I've disabled root user's ability to log in).

B) Using the existing SSH key (which I'm unable to add to bitbucket as mentioned above) to access bitbucket as a different user (not root user, but perhaps the username I use to log into the Ubuntu server?)  In order to pull code off the bitbucket repository using this approach, would I first have to set a SSH key under my home directory (/home/myusername/.ssh)on the Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is the remote server connecting to the bitbucket repository via SSH when I'm unable to add the SSH public key to bitbucket?

The SSH-handshake protocol is used when initializing the connection to Bitbucket and this involves determining which key could be used. In this case, each key in root/.ssh will be tried and when one is accepted by Bitbucket then will that one connection be established (you may have a root/.ssh/config that states which key to use, then only that will be used)

SSH-keys are associated with single accounts on Bitbucket (1-1 relationship) and when given an SSH-key (from the handshake process) Bitbucket knows which account to use. Apparently, someone is already using this key.

> Should I instead create a new SSH key in the Ubuntu server and try to add that (the public key part) to bitbucket, then access bitbucket using the new key?

Yes, you need at least one key for each account on Bitbucket that should access Bitbucket from your development server.

> If I don't have the paraphrase that the server keeps prompting me to enter after typing the git pull command, what's the best approach to pulling code from the repository?

It's unclear why you use root to access Bitbucket, but if it's possible I would have my own key in my home directory `/home/myusername/.ssh` (and have my own clone of the remote repository on the server).

I case that root is running some tasks that involve pulling from Bitbucket then you could create a separate Bitbucket account for it and use separate keys for that account.

Comment: Turns out I only needed to create a new SSH key for my username and add that key to bitbucket.  I was then able to connect to bitbucket via SSH using my username (as opposed to root user) by not starting the git pull/push commands with sudo (sudo causes the connection to reference root user's SSH key; excluding sudo causes connection to look for SSH key pertaining to my username).